# Allow user to execute “repquota -g /”

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, quota, disk-space-utilization

I need to allow an user to execute "repquota -g /" from a script without superuser permissions on debian Wheezy. I would not allow all superuser permissions to the user (in my case it is the www-data user). The user cannot access to the file //aquota.group so I tried to create a group "quotarep" but the root cannot chown the file:

```
chown root:quotarep //aquota.group
chown: changing ownership of `//aquota.group': Operation not permitted
```

I am thinking to deploy a cron job to export the result of "repquota -g/" on a file but I don't think it is a good way. Do you know how I can solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual:

> Only the super-user may view quotas which are not their own.

The typical solution is than to set up a password free `sudo` policy for www-data :

```
 # /etc/sudoers
 www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/repquota -g
```

And in your script you can than call `sudo /usr/sbin/repquota -g`